# post request to server does not send the content of textfields?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to send the content of my textfields firstname and lastname with my button sendpost to my php server. Once I run my app and fill my textfields with some random text and press send, I receive an e-mail on my server but there is no content.

```
(void) sendAction{

    NSError *error = nil;    
    NSString *postparams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"info=%@_%@",firstname.text,lastname.text];   
    NSData * postdata = [postparams dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];    
    NSString * postlength= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postdata length]];    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://faketest.com/test/mail.php"]];    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
    [request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];    
    [request setHTTPBody:postdata];

    NSData * rawdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];    
    NSString *rawdatastring =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:rawdata  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    NSLog(@"%@",rawdatastring);

}
```

Comment: simplify, try sending hardcoded data, for example: NSString *postparams = @"Bla bla bla"; That should rule out some things, if you still don't get anything then the problem lies in your post syntax, and than you will be in a position to ask right questions and search for right answers...

Comment: @AntonijoDev ok thx, i just tried it with the hardcoded data and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be because you're using a "Current-Type" header, instead of the usual "Content-Type" header. Try the following and see if it solves the problem:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: @Benny: even with hardcoded postparams? What thread is sendAction being called from?

Comment: from my button:
sendpost =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake.....;
sendpost addTarget:self action:@selector(sendAction)forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView:sendpost];

Comment: @Benny: Hmm, I don't see anything else that could be causing it in that case. Perhaps the issue resides in the PHP code? Can you share a snippet of that as well?

Comment: @Benny: actually another thing to try would be to URL-encode the postparams string before converting it to NSData. The easiest way would be to use the stringByUrlEncoding category method described here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/08/url-encoding/

Comment: Heere is the PHP code from my partner.
<?php
 header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
 $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
 $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
 $text = "not set";
 if(!empty($_POST["text"])){
  $text = $_POST["text"];
 }
 $lat = $_POST["lat"];
 $lon = $_POST["lon"];
 $dieMessage =$firstname." ".$lastname."\n".$text."\n";
 $dieMessage .="Lat:".$lat."\n";
 $dieMessage .="Lon:".$lon;
 mail("blabla@gmail.com", "gps daten", $dieMessage);
 //echo 'Email abgeschickt!';
 echo $dieMessage;

?>

Comment: Your POST parameters are incorrect. Use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&lastname=%@",firstname.text,lastname.text];

Comment: ok i changed this, but i still dont get the textfield content.thanks for your attention

Comment: do i have to add something in the appdelegate viewcontroller? 
i only have my code in the sendviewcontroller.m and .h